# Finding a subgroup $H$ of $\mathbb{Z_{p^2}}\oplus\mathbb{Z_{p^2}}$ with given condition.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism

> **Question**: Find a subgroup $H$ of $\mathbb{Z_{p^2}}\oplus\mathbb{Z_{p^2}}$ such that
> $(\mathbb{Z_{p^2}}\oplus\mathbb{Z_{p^2}})/H$ is isomorphic to
> $\mathbb{Z_p}\oplus\mathbb{Z_p}$

**My attempt:** it is given in **Hint** that, consider $H=\{x\in\mathbb{Z_{p^2}}\oplus\mathbb{Z_{p^2}} : x^p=(0,0)\}$

I first proved that $H$ is subgroup of $\mathbb{Z_{p^2}}\oplus\mathbb{Z_{p^2}}$ of order $p^2$. Then as $|(\mathbb{Z_{p^2}}\oplus\mathbb{Z_{p^2}})/H|=|\mathbb{Z_{p^2}}\oplus\mathbb{Z_{p^2}}|/|H|=p^2$

**Hence we have** $(\mathbb{Z_{p^2}}\oplus\mathbb{Z_{p^2}})/H≈ \mathbb{Z_{p^2}}$ **or** $≈\mathbb{Z_p}\oplus\mathbb{Z_p}$

**Now to show** $(\mathbb{Z_{p^2}}\oplus\mathbb{Z_{p^2}})/H≈\mathbb{Z_p}\oplus\mathbb{Z_p}$
we must show that $(\mathbb{Z_{p^2}}\oplus\mathbb{Z_{p^2}})/H$ has no element of order $p^2$ but I think it has element of order $p^2$ so that $(\mathbb{Z_{p^2}}\oplus\mathbb{Z_{p^2}})/H≈\mathbb{Z_{p^2}}$ hence subgroup $H$ given in hint is wrong! ** Or I had done some mistake. Please tell me how to show $(\mathbb{Z_{p^2}}\oplus\mathbb{Z_{p^2}})/H≈\mathbb{Z_p}\oplus\mathbb{Z_p}$

Please help...

Comment: You say that you think your quotient group has an element of order $p^2$. What element is that?

Comment: @peterag sir, I think $(1,1)+H$

Comment: Just to make sure of your notation: the $H$ of the hint consists of those elements killed by (multiplication by) $p$. Agree?

Comment: That is: $H= \{x \in G \mid p\cdot x = 0\}$, where $G= {\mathbb Z/p^2}\times {\mathbb Z/p^2}$. Agree?

Comment: @peterag yes sir I agree but then what?

Comment: So, can you see that $p\cdot (1,1) \in H$? Therefore the element $(1,1) +H$ should have order $p$ in the quotient group, and not $p^2$ as you suggested.

Comment: @peterag thank you so much sir. Got it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: From your observations above, it suffices to show that there is no element in $\mathbb{Z}_p^2\oplus \mathbb{Z}_p^2/H$ of oerder $p^2$. An element $x+H$ has order $p$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p^2\oplus \mathbb{Z}_p^2/H$ if $x^p\in H$, now consider the definition of $H$.